# Callback function when fetching N latest records from mongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having trouble writing a callback for fetching the latest N records from a mongoDB collection. I'm creating an Express route called /pp that will return stuff in my DB. I used to just return everything in it, so something like:

```html
app.get("/pp", function (req, res) {
  PPOverTime.find({}, function (error, documents) {
      res.send(documents);
    });
});
```

(PPovertime is the name of my collection btw)

But I want to now take the last N records placed into the DB, which according to the Stack Overflow post linked above is accomplished via "db.foo.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(30)" for last 30 entries, for example.

So where do I put the callback function to return the response? I tried:

```html
app.get("/pp", function (req, res) {
  PPOverTime.find()
    .limit(30)
    .sort({ _id: -1 }, function (error, documents) {
      res.send(documents);
    });
});
```

But this gives an error because the sort function can only take in one argument. I guess more generally how do I do this asynchronously if I have more than one function to run on a find() call? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
app.get("/pp", function (req, res) {
  PPOverTime.find()
    .limit(30)
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Comment: this returned an error, says that "TypeError: PPOverTime.find(...).limit(...).sort(...).toArray is not a function"

Comment: Try removing toArray() and try. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, here's how I did it.

```html
// limit to returning only the last 20 entries
app.get("/pp", function (req, res) {
  let q = PPOverTime.find().limit(20).sort({ _id: 1 });
  q.exec(function (err, data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: I feel exec is an old way of doing using callbacks. [then and catch] i.e Promises helps in better code readability.